# rails css class="current"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add a `class="current"` to the current page in the navigation 
to the first `<li>`. So the html should look like 
`<li id="nav-home" class="current">` but only to the current page.

```
<% subjects.each do |subject| %>
  <li id="nav-<%= subject.name %>" >
    <a <%= link_to(subject.name, :action => 'show') %></a>
    <ul>
    <% subject.pages.visible.sorted.each do |page| %>
      <li ><%= link_to(page.name, :action => 'show', :id => page.permalink) %></li>
    </ul>   
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: your right, but  I am so new to all this is the best I could come up with I'll try to make it more clear the next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `current_page?` to check if the page you are linking to is the current page.

```
<li id="nav-<%= subject.name %>" class="<%= current_page?( page_i_am_linking_to ) ? 'current' : '' %>" >
```

This will set the class to "current" or leave it empty.

I did not really understand how you build your link/ to what you are linking, that is why I used "page_i_am_linking_to". You need to replace this with something valid.

See also the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F)

Answer (score 0):

You want to have an instance variable `@current_page_id` that is set to the page that your rendering, then just add the class to the element you want  to have it, like so (I chose to put it on the list element):

```
<% subjects.each do |subject| %>
<li id="nav-<%= subject.name %>" >
    <a <%= link_to(subject.name, :action => 'show') %> </a>
 <ul>
<% subject.pages.visible.sorted.each do |page| %>
 <li class="<%= @current_page_id == page.id ? 'current' : '' %>"><%= link_to(page.name, :action => 'show', :id => page.permalink) %></li>
 </ul>

<% end %>
```

if you want to put it on the link instead:

```
<li ><%= link_to(page.name, :action => 'show', :id => page.permalink, :class => @current_page_id == page.id ? 'current' : '') %></li>
```